# phpunit in org-mode src block

Tags: org-mode, php-mode

I'm using phpunit package 
https://github.com/nlamirault/phpunit.el and it works great with php files. 
But I have a simple php blog about refactoring ex: http://phprefactor.com/refactorings/decompose-conditional and I would like to run phpunit test in org-mode src block. That would be extremely usefull in blogging about php :)

[image: php code]
[image: php code in org src block]

Comment: `(defun org-babel-execute:phpunit (body params)
     "Orgmode Babel PHP evaluate function for `BODY' with `PARAMS'."
     (let* ((cmd "phpunit EmailTest.php")
     (body (concat "<?php\n" body "\n?>")))
       (org-babel-eval cmd body)
       ))`

I find out that this works when I set precise file, But how can it be done to run the code in #+BEGIN_SRC ? Because when i try it gives "Code block produced no output."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I make it work. The main problem is that org-mode shell source blocks do not capture stderr. You can read more about this [here](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/04/Redirecting-stderr-in-org-mode-shell-blocks/). So normally you will not see output if one of the test fails. 
Solution for this is to save code block to temporary file and then running org-babel-sh-command on the file which in case of failure redirect stderr to stdout.
I create new config for phpunit:

```
   (defun org-babel-execute:phpunit (body params)
 "Orgmode Babel PHP evaluate function for `BODY' with `PARAMS'."
 (let* ((cmd "./phpunithack.sh")
    (body (concat "<?php\n" body "\n?>")))
    (write-region body  nil "/home/slk500/.emacs.d/EmailTest.php")
   (org-babel-eval cmd body)
   ))
```

and my script phpunithack.sh looks like this:

```
exec 2>&1
```

phpunit EmailTest.php

:

Example src block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC phpunit
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class EmailTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testOne(): void
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    } 

    public function testTwo(): void
    {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    } 

} 
#+END_SRC
```